# Does Elm has an equivalent of Haskell's As-Pattern

Tags: elm

In Haskell, you can write

```hs
f x@(a, b, c) = x
```

Does Elm have an equivalent of this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, Elm uses the [ML variant of that syntax](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html#@concepts64), which is a postfix `as name` instead of Haskell's prefix `name@`:

```
f ((a, b, c) as x) = x
```

Comment: yeee! more parenthesis!